# Processing a list of Map<String,List<Object>> in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to create a single map from list of maps. Which contains only key "1" and all the values of key "1" across different maps under that list using Java 8 stream API.

```
List<Map<String,Object>> list=new ArrayList<>();
Map<String,Object> map1=new HashMap<>();
map1.put("1", Arrays.asList(new String[] {"A"}));
map1.put("2", Arrays.asList(new String[] {"B"}));

Map<String,Object> map2=new HashMap<>();
map2.put("1", Arrays.asList(new String[] {"C"}));
map2.put("2", Arrays.asList(new String[] {"D"}));
```

Required output :- `{1=[A, C]}`

Comment: Why don't you declare `list` as `List<Map<String,List<Object>>>`? Otherwise why isn't `{1=[[A], [C]]}` the expected output?

Comment: @ernest_k I can Change the declaration to List<Map<String,List<Object>>> but I require output as {1=[A, C]}. {1=[A, C]}  will be list of list right ?

Comment: @Chirag Right, that is exactly what is unclear with your question right now. Given the current code and `List<Map<String,List<Strinig>>>` as input type, the very first question you should ask yourself is why do you need such a complex representation of data, is there no way tto simplify it?

Comment: @Naman Need to return two lists from a process. So I am maintaining a map for it and that process can return multiple map, which makes it List of map. Any better suggestion

Answer (score 5):

Because you have only one entry, then in this case, you need just to focus on the values, and for the key you can just use `"1"`, for that you can create a Map like this :

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
result.put("1", list.stream()
        .filter(e -> e.containsKey("1"))
        .flatMap(e -> e.values().stream())
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Or as stated by [Lino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59892097/processing-a-list-of-mapstring-listobject-in-java-8/59892412?noredirect=1#comment105912484_59892412) in the comment, you can also use :

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = list.stream()
    .filter(e -> e.containsKey("1"))
    .flatMap(e -> e.values().stream())
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> "1"));
```

Comment: if you don't want to put into a map directly, you could use a groupingBy collector instead of toList: `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> "1", i -> i))`

Comment: @LinosaysReinstateMonica I don't get you sorry

Comment: Sorry I meant `groupingBy(i -> "1")` as can be seen [here](https://ideone.com/WFYcvI). Also i noticed that your code doesn't compile. Your stream collects into a `List<List<String>>` I think you missed a flatMap

Comment: Thank you @LinosaysReinstateMonica good idea, I put it in my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
Map<String, List<Object>> result = list.stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.containsKey("1"))
            .map(entry -> (List<Object>) entry.get("1"))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(t1 -> "1", 
                          ArrayList::new, (l1, l2) -> { l1.addAll(l2);return l1; }));
```

or use `groupingBy` collector :

```
Map<String, List<Object>> result2 = list.stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.containsKey("1"))
            .flatMap(entry -> ((List<Object>) entry.get("1")).stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t->"1",Collectors.
                        collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),ArrayList::new)));
```

Comment: Why not use `groupingBy`?

Answer (score 4):

> As mentioned by [@ernest_k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59892097/processing-a-list-of-mapstring-listobject-in-java-8/59892647#comment105912016_59892097) you should declare `list` as: `List<Map<String, List<String>>>`

You can use a `groupingBy` collector:

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = list.stream()
    .map(m -> m.get("1"))
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> "1"));
```

You can get rid of the intermediate `filter` with this. But this may be more confusing (and effectively does the same):

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = list.stream()
    .map(m -> m.get("1"))
    .flatMap(l -> l == null ? Stream.empty() : l.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> "1"));
```

Comment: Why don't you use this `Map<String, List<String>> result = list.stream().filter(m -> m.containsKey("1"))
    .flatMap(m -> m.get("1").stream()).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(l -> "1"));`

Comment: @RavindraRanwala that works as well, but does also effectively the same doesn't it? The map implementations I know almost always check if `get(key) != null` for `containsKey`